# Use of temporary files and memory when using tar to backup very _large_ files with compression

Tags: linux, bash, gzip, tar

When backing up one or more _very_large_ files using tar with compression (-j or -z) how does GNU tar manage the use of temporary files and memory?

Does it backup and compress the files block by block, file by file, or some other way?

Is there a difference between the way the following two commands use temporary files and memory?

```
tar -czf data.tar.gz ./data/*
```

```
tar -cf - ./data/* | gzip > data.tar.gz
```

Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Though reading the GNU tar documentation would tell you that its equivalent to piping, as the compressors used are all stream compressors...

Comment: Having read through the documentation (https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/gzip.html) I'm actually not at all sure that the way tar works is the same in both cases (section 8.1.1.1 seems to describe at lease one difference).  What I'm trying to do is work out what I need to check in terms of the size of the data set, the available memory and disk space before I launch the command in order to be reasonably confident that it will work.  I can subdivide the data set but this is expensive (in terms of time)...

Comment: @Cyrus - Understand where you are comming from but I'm trying to understand if I need to or even can check the available resouces before deciding to invoke tar or subdivide the dataset.

Comment: @Chris - I went through the manual earlier and having done so I'm not at all sure that what actually happens is the same, even if the results are similar (in particular section 8.1.1.1 actually suggests that the code used may be entirely different).  

The source code obviously holds the answer but there is quite a lot of it!

Answer (score 0):

No temporary files are used by either command.  `tar` works completely in a streaming fashion.  Packaging and compressing are completely separated from each other and also done in a piping mechanism when using the `-z` or `-j` option (or similar).

For each file `tar` it puts into an archive, it computes a file info datagram which contains the file's path, its user, permissions, etc., and also its size.  This needs to be known up front (that's why putting the output of a stream into a tar archive isn't easy without using a temp file).  After this datagram, the plain contents of the file follows.  Since its size is known and already part of the file info ahead, the end of the file is unambiguous.  So after this, the next file in the archive can follow directly.  In this process no temporary files are needed for anything.

This stream of bytes is given to any of the implemented compression algorithms which *also* do not create any temporary files.  Here I'm going out on a limb a bit because I don't know all compression algorithms by heart, but all that I ever came in touch with do not create temporary files.